# parseInt acting strangely - possibly

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2008, parseint

I have simple little js function that is called by a custom validator for a textbox, basically to check if a time falls outside of a particular range.. the format of the time is '**hh:mm**'
the ranges are written to js variables by the asp.net page read from the web.config..

here is the offending bit of the function..

```
function WarnOfOOOFlightTime(source, e){
    var val = e.Value.split(':');
    var minVal = oooMin.split(':');
    var maxVal = oooMax.split(':');

    var valHrs = parseInt(val[0]); //"07" here parses to 7
    var valMins = parseInt(val[1]);

    var minValHrs = parseInt(minVal[0]); //"08" here parses to 0!
    var minValMins = parseInt(minVal[1]);

....
```

sure its something simple, but I am not getting it..
as usual any help much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the radix parameter to `parseInt()`, otherwise it'll attempt to treat numbers with leading zeroes as octal.

```
var n = parseInt(str, 10);
```

Comment: +1 Doesn't explain the stated behaviour in that `parseInt('07')` should still be 7 in Octal but I assume the description in the question is lacking.

Comment: @MartinSmith that was my assumption too.

Comment: fair do's yes was actually always 08 that failed 07 was working each time - amended question, was a typo